# Cgi not executing python

Tags: python, apache2, cgi

I'm having a problem getting CGI to work for Python.

I've added

```
Options ExecCGI
AddHandler cgi-script cgi py pl
```

inside /etc/apache2/sites-available/default within

and now Perl works, but Python gives out a 500 Internal Server Error..

EDIT:

This if the current 'default' file

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

    DocumentRoot /var/www
    <Directory />
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride AuthConfig
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all

            AddHandler mod_python .py
            PythonHandler mod_python.publisher
            PythonDebug On
    </Directory>

    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /var/www/cgi-bin/
    <Directory "/var/www/cgi-bin/">
            Options +ExecCGI
            AddHandler cgi-script .cgi .py .pl
            Allow from all
    </Directory>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: do you have `#!/usr/bin/python` as the first line of your `.py` files?

Comment: Yes I do. The .py file has that and just print "Hello World" below it

Comment: And did you do a chmod ugo+x on the file?

Comment: Yes I did. I've tried every possible file permission

Comment: Don't you need to print a Content-Type header?

Comment: @fuzzy lollipop: Sounds like an answer.  Please post it so we can vote it up.

Comment: You should be able to find *something* of use in the Apache error log when you try to load the page. (Is Python itself readable/executable to the web server user?)

Answer (score 1):

Try renaming the .py files to .cgi, it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the python CGI server instead of apache,if that can meet your needs.

```
python -m CGIHTTPServer {port number:default 8000}
```